# Multiple Switch Button background-color CSS

Tags: css, z-index, background-color, slide

I have problem in a custom switch button group. I want to act my switch buttons background like in this demo http://codepen.io/vanderlanth/pen/yYeryP but when I give background-color to the elements in this demo, the sliding part become invisible while sliding between elements occasionally. Can anyone help me with that ?

You can check what I'm trying to do from http://labs.epcsht.com/nash/index.html under Switch section.

```
<div class="switchButtonCont">
<input type="radio" name="switch" value="Male" id="switchButton-1" hidden="hidden"/>
<label for="switchButton-1">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="switch" value="Female" id="switchButton-2" hidden="hidden" checked/>
<label for="switchButton-2">Female</label>
<input type="radio" name="switch" value="Both" id="switchButton-3" hidden="hidden"/>
<label for="switchButton-3">Both</label>
<input type="radio" name="switch" value="Meraba" id="switchButton-4" hidden="hidden"/>
<label for="switchButton-4">Meraba</label>
</div>
```

You can check

Answer (score 0):

I whipped up a proof of concept, but I think you'll probably need to get some JS involved to make this more extendable...

revised markup:

```
<fieldset class="cont">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="o1">
  <label for="o1">
    Opt 1
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="o2">
  <label for="o2"> 
    Opt 1
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="o3">
  <label for="o3">
    Opt 1
  </label>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</fieldset>
```

demo css

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  label {
    border: 1px solid;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  input {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    opacity: .000001;
  }
}

.slider {
  width: 33.3333%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
}

#o2:checked ~ .slider {
  left: 33.33333%;
}

#o3:checked ~ .slider {
  left: 66.66667%;
}
```

Just an FYI, but using the `hidden` attribute in your example will make those radio buttons inaccessible to screen readers.

If these really are meant to be buttons, instead of radio options, you may also want to revise the markup to be something like:

```
<div class="cont>
  <button type="button" aria-pressed="true">
    Btn 1
  </button>
  <button type="button" aria-pressed="false">
    Btn 2
  </button>
  <button type="button" aria-pressed="false">
    Btn 3
  </button>
</div>
```

css would need to adjust accordingly as well.

hope this helps you along the way!